# Extruding from a poked face

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender.  I poked the face in the top of the crab claw then subdivided so I could get verticies.  I have selected the verticies(see image) [image] and now I extrude up to make a crab claw which looks ok on the outside but on the inside I've extruded up all these faces which are difficult to delete fully because they are on the inside (see photo) [image]How do I extrude the verticies without all the unecessary faces, I only want the outside faces

Comment: Hello, it looks like there's a problem with your topology here, could you please share your file?

Answer (score 0):

You must be in 'Edge mode' insteaf of 'Vertex Mode'.
Select the edges all arround the circle and extrude.

[image]

[image]

It works !

Comment: thankyou so much

Comment: @Red Wellcome. A thank you is usually expressed here with an upvote, or by marking the answer as "Accepted Answer" if your question was answered satisfactorily. All optional, of course, but it shows other users that your question has been solved. Thank you!